# Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP): can FN beat NN given these conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, induction

Take the traveling salesman problem, but with three slight twists:

1. You can choose a different start vertex for each of the two algorithms.
2. Each path from one vertex to another is of unique, arbitrary length (irrespective of the distances between the cities and they don't intersect).
3. Each algorithm goes to each vertex once and only once (it doesn't return to its starting vertex).

With these conditions, is it possible for a furthest neighbor algorithm to beat a nearest neighbor algorithm.

I've tried using induction, but condition 2 really throws it off. I see [this previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222637/travelling-salesman-can-the-furthest-neighbour-algorithm-beat-the-nearest-neigh) answers a similar question, but mine is slightly different for the above three reasons.

Comment: What attempts have you done? Please show your work.

Comment: Define FN(k) as the longest legal path from each city k and define NN similarly. At each city, k, FN(k)>NN(k), except for their last city. Thus, in order for the FN to go a shorter distance than the NN, FN(i)<NN(j) when the FN's ending city is i and the NN's ending city is j. However, FN(i) connects two cities and NN(j) connects two cities. If NN(j) was really actually big, it would have gone to through it already via the other city. If FN(i) was small, it would have already travelled through it via the other connecting city. If they don't take those, it will make their difference even bigger.

Comment: @Laufen Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes furthest neighbors first can beat nearest neighbors first search. This is simply done by example. Your condition 2 does not restrict anything. Important is that the lengths are unique and can not be changed. And intersections can be eliminated easily under keeping uniqueness if length are assigned and not real.

So in what cases does this preference make a difference?
Only if a mixed choice strategy is best and the graph is best solved with annealing and an optimization function than there will be a difference. Therefore the graph has to provide some arbitrariness. For example two nor more knots are connected by more than on path of different length. The there are removable edges that make fn or nn better.

Look at this [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) for some more indepth cases in the given literature.

Neither fn nor nn are optimal strategies for the general case of the tsp. This indicates that there are either cases where one of the selection of the next path of the other is better. It is always an experiment to calculate a given total path length depending on the choice of fn or nn. This is not so a great influence that avoiding longer pathes taking shorter once. It has no influence if the compare pathes have to be taken to reach each knot.

If the graph has a cover of the knot with only longer and only shorter pathes than this is another trivial case. Than always the selection of the nearest, shortes path is the optimal choice.

There are solvable graphs with only some choice are present. If there is a mixture of such choices then not all edges might be meet and the graph can be unsolvable for tsp. So in graphs with directed edges with different length in each directions are example for the deep need of sorrow calculations and comparisons. Graphs without that are not a problem and often again both perform the very same. This a priori undecidability is a first indicator that different performances come with the given tsp graph. Whether this is just the case for bidirectional differently weighted graphs and the total visit constraints should be clear.

The easiest example is a tsp graph with two knots and one bidirectional path. One direction is longer than the other. Starting from the knot in the shorter direction favours nn, starting in the opposite direction favors fn. This is because the other preference has no solution to compare to. There are cases were fn is better and were nn is better and were both are the same. The start shows that tsp with two successive knots connected by bidirectional pathes gives a longer minimal necessary  description already. So if long-short and short-long appears neither strategy can be applied. Only long-long and short-short can be discussed.